# cvReleaseCapture() error

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

To make my question clearer, please view the following codes below:

For snapping image:

```
void CameraTest ::on_snapButton_clicked()
{
    CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0); // capture from video device #0


    cvSetCaptureProperty(capture ,CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH , 800); 
    cvSetCaptureProperty(capture ,CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT , 600); 


    if(!cvGrabFrame(capture))  //if no webcam detected or failed to capture anything
    {              // capture a frame 
        cout << "Could not grab a frame\n\7";
        exit(0);
    }

    IplImage* img=cvRetrieveFrame(capture);           // retrieve the captured frame

    cv::Mat imageContainer(img);
    image=imageContainer;
    cv::imshow("Mat",image);  

    //cvReleaseCapture(&capture);  When I enable this, and run the programming calling this, there will be an error. 
}
```

Now, the program to display the image:

```
      void CameraTest ::on_processButton_clicked() 
      {
          cv::imshow("image snapped", image);

          //my image processing steps...
      }
```

When I enable the `cvReleaseCapture(&capture)` line, I recieve the following error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00fc3ff5 in CameraTest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x042e1030.
```

When I comment/remove the line, I am able to display image properly upon clicking the other button, but when I want to snap new images, I have to click the button a few times, which is a major flaw in the program. Is there anyway to go around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- avoid the outdated c-api (IplImages, Cv*functions)  stick with the c++ api.
- the images you get from a capture point to memory *inside* the cam-driver. if you don't clone() the image, and release the capture, you got a dangling pointer.
- don't create a new capture for each shot. (cam needs some 'warm-up' time so it'll be slow as hell).
  keep one instance around in your class instead

---

```
class CameraTest 
{
    VideoCapture capture;         // make it a class - member
    CameraTest () : capture(0)    // capture from video device #0
    {
         capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH , 800); 
         capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT , 600); 
    }

    // ...
};

void CameraTest ::on_snapButton_clicked()
{
    Mat img;                // temp var pointing todriver mem    

    if(!capture.read(img))  //if no webcam detected or failed to capture anything
    {
        cout << "Could not grab a frame\n\7";
        exit(0);
    }

    image = img.clone();      // keep our member var alive
    cv::imshow("Mat",image);  

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Berak! It worked, plus one and accepted answer for you. Appreciate it(:

Answer (score 1):

Replace :

```
if(!cvGrabFrame(capture))  //if no webcam detected or failed to capture anything
    {              // capture a frame 
        cout << "Could not grab a frame\n\7";
        exit(0);
    }
```

by

```
if ( !capture )
        {
            cout << "Could not grab a frame\n\7";
            exit(0);

        }
```

and replace

```
  IplImage* img=cvRetrieveFrame(capture);
```

by

```
IplImage* img = cvQueryFrame( capture );
```

cvQueryFrame  Grabs and returns a frame from video  or camera. This function is  a `combination` of cvGrabFrame and cvRetrieveFrame in one call. The returned image should not be released or modified by user.

Comment: Doesn't work, but +1 for the suggestion. Appreciate it.